# What kind of drum sampling options does Audiokit have?

Tags: audiokit

Working in audio kit and I am looking to understand how people have incorporated drums. Obviously, the sampler is an option, but I am wondering if there is a built in option similar to some of the basic synthesis options.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. I personally like the AppleSampler/MidiSampler like in the example but instead of using audio files you can create a EXS Sampler instrument in Logic where you can assign notes for different velocities. AppleSampler can also load AUPresets made in GarageBand and SoundFonts (SF2). The DunneAudioKit Sampler is an option if you are working with SFZ files, but I think that might be a work-in-progress in AudioKit 5. Loading WAV files directly into AppleSampler is also a good option if you just want one shot sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're mostly talking about *playback* of samples, not *recording*.

The best built-in option I've seen (other than AppleSampler/MidiSampler) is AudioPlayer, which lets you load in a sample and play it back on demand (from an on-screen pad, etc). MIDIListener can then help you respond to external MIDI events, etc. It works (I have a pretty big branch in my app where I tried it), but not sure it works well.

I wouldn't recommend DunneAudioKit Sampler for drums. There is no one-shot playback (so playing the same note in quick succession will cut off the previous note, even if you mess with the release). If you're trying to build a complex/realistic acoustic drum instrument, you'll also want round-robins so that variations of the same hit can be played, which Dunne also doesn't have. It can load SFZ files, but only a very limited subset of SFZ's opcodes (so again, it's missing things like round robins, mute groups, one-shot, etc).

Having gone down all those roads, I would suggest starting with AppleSampler, and I would build the EXS or aupreset file in Logic or Mainstage rather than trying to build something programmatically.

If your needs are *really* simple, the examples in AudioKit's recently released [drum pad playground](https://audiokitpro.com/drumpadplayground/) is a great place to start, loading single samples into a specific note on AppleSampler.